# PfQuery orQueryWithSubqueries crash app when i make run

Tags: ios, tableview, parse-platform, pfquery

Hello everyone I'm working with and I'm using parse.com PFQuery orQuerywithSubqueries

Until now everything worked very well and now I need to add a fourth query, but the app keeps crashing when I make the run ... does anyone know why this happens ?

```
- (void)  QueryForPost {
    
    PFUser CurrentGoUser * = [ PFUser currentUser ] ;
    
    PFQuery QueryForFriend * = [ PFQuery queryWithClassName : FF_AMICIZIE_CLASS ] ;
    [ QueryForFriend whereKey : FF_AMICIZIE_A_USER equalTo : CurrentGoUser ] ;
    [ QueryForFriend whereKey : FF_AMICIZIE_STATO equalTo : @ " Confirmed "];
    [ QueryForFriend includeKey : FF_AMICIZIE_DA_USER ] ;
        
    PFQuery QueryForPost * = [ PFQuery queryWithClassName : FF_POST_CLASS ] ;
    [ QueryForPost whereKey : FF_POST_FLASH_POST_BOOLEANVALUE equalTo : [ NSNumber numberWithBool : YES] ] ;
    [ QueryForPost whereKey : FF_POST_SCELTI equalTo : CurrentGoUser ] ;

    PFQuery normalPostByFriends * = [ PFQuery queryWithClassName : FF_POST_CLASS ] ;
    [ normalPostByFriends whereKey : FF_POST_FLASH_POST_BOOLEANVALUE equalTo : [ NSNumber numberWithBool : NO ]] ;
    [ normalPostByFriends whereKey : FF_POST_UTENTE matchesKey : FF_AMICIZIE_DA_USER inquery : QueryForFriend ] ;
    
    PFQuery normalPostByUser * = [ PFQuery queryWithClassName : FF_POST_CLASS ] ;
    [ normalPostByUser whereKey : FF_POST_FLASH_POST_BOOLEANVALUE equalTo : [ NSNumber numberWithBool : NO ]] ;
    [ normalPostByUser whereKey : FF_POST_UTENTE equalTo : CurrentGoUser ] ;
    
    PFQuery queryForGoPointStatus * = [ PFQuery queryWithClassName : @ " goPoint "];
    [ queryForGoPointStatus whereKey : @ " AssegnatoDa " equalTo : CurrentGoUser ] ;


    PFQuery * query = [ PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries : @ [ QueryForPost , normalPostByFriends , normalPostByUser , queryForGoPointStatus ]] ;
    [ query includeKey : FF_POST_UTENTE ] ;
    [ includeKey query : @ " AssegnatoDa "];
    [ query OrderByDescending : FF_CREATEDAT ] ;
  
    [ query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock : ^ ( NSArray * results, NSError * error ) {
       
        if (! error) {
            ArrayforPost = [ [ NSMutableArray alloc] init ] ;
            for ( PFObject * object in results ) {
                [ ArrayforPost addObject : object ] ;
            }
            [ self.FFTableView reloadData ] ;
        Else { }
            NSLog ( @ " Erroreeeee :% @" , error) ;
        }
    } ] ;
   
}
```

Comment: Give details of the exception, name and stack trace.

Comment: I tried to insert a breakpoint exeption but it stops here, I did not return any kind of error more 'specific understanding

     PFQuery * query = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries: @ [QueryForPost, normalPostByFriends, normalPostByUser, queryForGoPointStatus]];

Comment: Add an all exception breakpoint. But just show the log you get when it terminates. Also, did you copy paste your code because it doesn't look like it compiles?

Comment: Forcing the breakpoint gives me this ... 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'All sub queries of an or query should be on the same class'
*** First throw call stack:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception message says it all: `All sub queries of an or query should be on the same class`. So you can only use predicates on `FF_POST_CLASS` or `FF_AMICIZIE_CLASS`, but not both. As it's an `OR` predicate you can just make 2 requests and merge the results.

Comment: It in fact had translated this part ... then how can I recognize the post if there is a vote of the Current User or not? I also tried the query just as you had suggested but does not create differences ... the action of the button is always the same.

Comment: Looking again, it's actually the `@ " goPoint "` class name. But that also can't be a valid class name because it has spaces at the start and end...

Comment: -(BOOL)Like:(PFObject *)PostLiked {
    for (PFObject *Likes in UpVoteCurrentUser) {
        if ([[[Likes objectForKey:@"Oggetto_Votato"]objectId] isEqualToString:PostLiked.objectId])  I solved it by passing the array to the object